# casting Subclass to SubInterface implemented by SuperClass

Tags: java, inheritance, casting

my structure goes like this:

```
interface SuperInterface{}

interface SubInterface extends SuperInterface{}

abstract class BaseClass implements SuperInterface{}

class SubClass extends BaseClass {}
```

and what i want to do is cast SubClass to SubInterface

```
SubInterface instanceOfSubClass = (SubInterface) new SubClass ();
```

but i am getting a casting exception.

so why can't i cast to SubInterface even that it extends SuperInterface and dosen't add anything ? it is just a wrapper to SuperInterface which is implemented by BaseClass

Comment: "why can't i cast to SubInterface even that it extends SuperInterface and dosen't add anything" Because `SubInterface` is not the same as `SuperInterface`: they are different classes. Why do you need `SubInterface` in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"SubClass" inherits from BaseClass which implements SuperInterface

So "SubClass" conforms to types "BaseClass" and "SuperInterface"

You cannot cast to "SubInterface" because SubInterface is a different type. Even if you don't add any functions to it and just use ist as a Wrapper, it es another type

```
SuperInterface
    -BaseClass
        --SubClass
    -SubInterface
```

You can see, SubClass is not in the inheritance path of SubInterface

Answer (score 1):

your hierarchy looks like that

```
                      SuperInterface
                            |
         ---------------------------------------
         |                                     |
       SubInterface                            |
                                           BaseClass                
                                               |
                                               |
                                            SubClass
```

And as you see from this diagram, `SubClass` has no  relation with `SubInterface`, hence you can not be casted to `SubInterface`

Answer (score 1):

You get the exception because `SubClass` is not an `SubInterface`. Your hierarchy looks like this:

```
SuperInterface
   BaseClass
      SubClass
```

In order to make this work `BaseClass` has to implement `SubInterface`. The hierarchy would then look like this:

```
SuperInterface
   SubInterface
      BaseClass
         SubClass
```

and you would be able to cast `SubClass` to `SubInterface`.

Comment: BaseClass is a third party library, i can not change it (superInterface is also a third party library) that is why i wrap them

Comment: I see, that's indeed a problem.

Answer (score 0):

See, here there are no relation between `SubInterface` & `SubClass`

so, obviously while you are going to cast it to each other and/or parent-child then it will throw `ClassCastException`

See, below Diagram for clear understanding.

[image]